# Auto-versioning assembly ignoring code changes brought in from SVN?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, assemblies, versioning

I have been having this issue for a while and maybe someone in the community can assist...basically I have auto-versioning configured for my assemblies "`<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.3.0.*")>`".

If I make a code change in my own working copy and build it will increment the revision number.  However, if I update my working copy with changes made by other developers and make a build without doing a code change myself - Visual Studio 2008 doesn't notice the change in code and doesn't recalculate the revision number.  I have resigned myself at this point to maintaining a phantom method that I change to force a new revision number before a build.

Any suggestions on how I can get the auto-versioning to correctly identify changes to the assembly when they are brought in from source control rather than done on the machine running the build?

Thanks.